# sql error with inner join mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, spring, inner-join

```
String sql = "set @row \\:=-1; SELECT ue.id, ue.Latitude, ue.Longitude, ue.Serving_Cell, ue.RSCP 
FROM ue INNER JOIN(
     SELECT id 
     from (
          SELECT @row \\:=@row+1 as rownum, id 
          from (
          select id from ue order by id) as sorted
                )as ranked  
      where rownum %20=0) as subset 
      on subset.id = ue.id 
where Operator like :operator ";

Query query = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery(sql);

query.setParameter("operator", "%" + operator + "%");

return query.list();
```

help me please to find my sql error 
console render me : 
GRAVE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [/SpringSecurity] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: **could not extract ResultSet**] with root cause
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; **check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near** 'SELECT ue.id, ue.Latitude, ue.Longitude, ue.Serving_Cell, ue.RSCP FROM ue INNER ' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

You try to execute 2 queries at once. You can only execute one at a time.

```
SELECT ue.id, ue.Latitude, ue.Longitude, ue.Serving_Cell, ue.RSCP 
FROM ue INNER JOIN(
     SELECT id 
     from (
          SELECT @row \\:=@row+1 as rownum, id 
          from (
          select id, @row 
          from ue, (select @row := -1) r
          order by id) as sorted
                )as ranked  
      where rownum %20=0) as subset 
      on subset.id = ue.id 
where Operator like :operator
```

But you can use a subquery to initialize a variable like this

```
(select @row := -1) r
```

Comment: you're totally right
thank you very much
with your help, it works now :D